# Divide by zero encountered in orthogonal regression with python (scipy.odr)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404134/orthogonal-distance-regression-in-python-meaning-of-returned-values) to perform [Orthogonal distance regression](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html#id1), it happens that for a specific data set, the routine encounters an error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/odrpack.py:361: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
return 1./numpy.power(sd, 2)
Beta: [ nan  nan]
Beta Std Error: [ 0.  0.]
Beta Covariance: [[ 0.  0.]
                  [ 0.  0.]]
Residual Variance: 0.0
Inverse Condition #: 0.0482240040702
Reason(s) for Halting:
   Numerical error detected
```

I thought it was due to some null elements in the regressed array, but it seems this is not the case. The documentation about the use of `scipy.odr` is very scarce, and I am not expert, so I don't know what is happening. What is `sd`? What are the calculations leading to this error?

EDIT: [this](http://pastebin.com/7uNXZ4u5) is the data set which returns the error, and [this](http://pastebin.com/myskqAgx) is the aray of associated errors.

Comment: Without an example data set, it's going to be difficult to identify the source of the error.

Comment: @b4hand, data sets added in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The associated errors must not be zero. They can be replaced with NaN values for example or removed from the dataset.